# Install Mail or Mailutils without postfix

Tags: apt, email, postfix

I have setup a postfix relay docker container which is binding to port 25. I want to be able to use the `mail` command from the host CLI, but every time I install `mailutils` via `apt` it installs `postfix` as well.

How can I install JUST `mailutils` so I can access the `mail` command without installing `postfix`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt update
apt purge postfix mailutils -y
apt autoremove -y
rm /etc/postfix/ -R
reboot
```

---

```
apt install mailutils sendmail -y
apt purge postfix -y
apt autoremove -y
systemctl stop sendmail
systemctl disable sendmail
reboot
```